# К чему относится причастный оборот?

Tags: причастный-оборот

РД 107.СКИП.0002.02-2010.

> В разделе "Методы настройки и проверки" указываются последовательность проведения операций настройки, положения органов регулировки (указывается при необходимости) и методика измерения параметров, не приведённых в технических условиях.

Подскажите, как мне доказать нормоконтролю, что причастный оборот "не приведённых в технических условиях" относится только к методам измерения, а не одновременно к трем однородным дополнениям?

Comment: Нормоконтролю доказать ничего невозможно. Разве что через суд - путем проведения лингво-семантической экспертизы.  Alex_ander дал вполне приемлемую лингвистическую канву для такой эеспертизы, но без юридического подтверждения для всякого рода проверяльщиков она ничего не будет значить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Причастный оборот здесь относится к "**параметрам**": это слово, с которым он согласован по падежу (родительный), причем падеж этот возникает в результате управления словом "измерения" (*измерения чего? - параметров, не приведённых там-то*), входящим в конкретный элемент перечисления (методика измерения). Ввиду явной подчинённости оборота *примыкающему* к нему существительному, находящиеся в таком же падеже существительные "настройки" и "органов" в восприятии читателя не конкурируют с "параметрами" (лишь после десятого прочтения можно заметить, что их можно попытаться притянуть к альтернативной версии). Кроме того, попытка отнести причастный оборот к другим частям высказывания порождает ложные смыслы: будто в технических условиях могут приводиться 1) "операции настройки" и 2) "органы регулировки" (физический объект) - это противоречит сути документа "технические условия", который регламентирует *параметры* продукции и не имеет отношения к настройке.